# Redireccionar desde Node App a React App

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

buenas tardes, queria saber si alguien sabe como redireccionar desde node.js a una pagina de React.js...
Les comento,desde Node.JS obtengo una respuesta de una API que estoy consumiendo, y directamente voy a una ruta que es '/PostPagoMP', esta ruta va a hacer una serie de instrucciones internamente, y finalmente quiero que me redireccione pero a la aplicacion de React.JS
Este es mi codigo

```
    router.get('/postPagoMP' ,async function(request, response) {
    let Estado = request.query.status;
    
    if(Estado === "approved"){
        console.log("ACA VIENEEE");
        proxy.web(request, response, { target: 'http://localhost:3000/' });
        //guardarPedido();
    }

    /*if(pedidoGuardado.insertId > 0)
    {
        response.json({
            Pago: request.query.payment_id,
            Estado: request.query.status,
            MerchantOrder: request.query.merchant_order_id,
            pedidoGuardado:pedidoGuardado
        })
    }else{
        response.json({
            data: "No se efectuo el pago ni el pedido"
        })
    }*/

});
```

Queria saber si alguno podia ayudarme sobre como redireccionar desde ese router.get que es de mi aplicacion backend(Node JS), hacia mi frontend(React JS). Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué puerto tienes el backend? Saludos

Comment: Hola, que tal , ya lo pude solucionar, ahi publico como lo hice, muchas gracias de todas formas @g.4 ! :)